# Replacing SOAP headers in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need to use soap to get some informations from one of our providers. They gave us the url to call and then left us pretty much in the dark. After searching we understood that the headers they use are different from the standard ones.

We need to send

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
     xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
     xmlns:com="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Commun.Interfaces.Request">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
```

So we tried to replace the regular header in the XML document by this one. It works, if we plint it before send it looks good.

But after sending we receive an exception :

```
looks like we got no XML document
```

and `$soap->__getLastRequest()` returns :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    
    xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The replace has been lost. We tried to send it with CURL also, modifying the XPL before, and the same exception shows up. So we don't really know what to do.

Thanks ahead for any help !